# Sentiment analysis with continuous scale for responses

Tags: predictive-modeling, deep-learning, regression, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to create a sentiment analysis system using deep learning (with R).
I have a review base of customer reviews which for each review the customer make a mark (from 0 to 10).

How can I do this, using marks in the range 0..10?  Is it possible?  In some tutorials, I see that authors use 0, 1 or -1 (0 for neutral, 1, positive and -1 for negative), and I'm not sure how to adjust to marks in the range 0..10.